# CVLC: alsa name?

Tags: alsa, vlc, cvlc

Someone know how to pass an alsa device name to cvlc?
I did

```
aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=SB
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=SB
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
hdmi:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, VT1708S Digital
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
```

and then edited vlcrc

```
alsa-audio-device=front:CARD=SB,DEV=0
```

I try also

```
alsa-audio-device=front:CARD=SB,DEV=0,0
```

But when i run cvlc give me device didn't exist,why?
The problem is on cvlc only,not on vlc gui
This is detailed output cvlc

```
VLC media player 2.0.6 Twoflower (revision 2.0.6-0-gbe9623c)
[0x1940e28] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x7f502cc01ad8] main demux error: corrupt module: /usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/demux/libmpc_plugin.so
[0x7f502cc01ad8] main demux error: corrupt module: /usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/demux/libsid_plugin.so
[0x7f502cc02a28] main decoder error: corrupt module: /usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/codec/libfluidsynth_plugin.so
[0x7f500c0069c8] main audio output error: corrupt module: /usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libpulse_plugin.so
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
ALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library (null)
ALSA lib conf.c:3777:(snd_config_update_r) hooks failed, removing configuration
[0x7f500c0069c8] alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "sysdefault:CARD=SB": No such file or directory
[0x7f500c0069c8] main audio output error: Audio output failed
[0x7f500c0069c8] main audio output error: The audio device "sysdefault:CARD=SB" could not be used:
No such file or directory.
[0x7f500c0069c8] oss audio output error: cannot open audio device (/dev/dsp)
[0x7f500c0069c8] main audio output error: no suitable audio output module
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
[0x7f502cdd4798] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
^Clibgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Because the device name is `front`; the `CARD=SB,DEV=0` part is telling you which device it corresponds to.</s>

You you need to do something like `alsa-audio-device=front`.

VLC, at least in my testing, will take either `front` or `front:CARD=SB,DEV=0`. However, it will error out if the device isn't actually usable. E.g., `aplay -L` will happily list HDMI ports with nothing plugged into them, but attempting to play to them will produce that "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "front": file or directory didn't exist

Comment: @elbarna That's weird—actually both `front` and `front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0` work on my machine. Are you sure you have that output? If I try an output that could be available but isn't (e.g., on my machine, `hdmi` is supported by the hardware, but there isn't anything connected to the HDMI ports) I get `alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "hdmi": No such file or directory`. Can anything else play to that output?

Comment: Of course is connected,with other players i have no problem,for example mplayer

Comment: @elbarna and what audio output are you using with `mplayer`? `-ao alsa:device=front` or something else?

Comment: yes,and work fine alsa:device=default,now i see the problem is not on vlc,but on cvlc only!

Comment: Solution found: was a bug of old vlc,updated to latest vlc all works
Thanks for help