# Debian dummy output alsa hooks failed

Tags: debian, audio, alsa

yesterday my audio working just fine. But, today after I upgrade packages using dist-upgrade pulseaudio detects no cards and just show dummy output in volume control.

After some research I thought it's related to alsa, so I do aplay -l
but it returned this

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3639:(config_file_open) cannot access file /etc/alsa/conf.d/10-rate-lav.conf
ALSA lib conf.c:3559:(snd_config_hooks_call) function 
snd_config_hook_load returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4013:(snd_config_update_r) hooks failed, removing configuration
```

I have no idea to what's wrong, I also have reverted the kernel to this version

```
Linux deb 4.17.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.17.17-1 (2018-08-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Related question: [CVLC: alsa name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202817/cvlc-alsa-name)

Comment: Hi @karel, thank you for your help. But my problem persist systemwide..

Comment: Looks like while upgrading, you messed up the ALSA configuration files in `/etc/alsa/`. First thing I'd do is to re-install all ALSA packages, and make sure they are all up to date and the same version.

Comment: I have the same problem. It appears pulseaudio has clobbered the symlinks under `/etc/alsa/conf.d/`. I am investigating the problem to see if I can fix it.

Comment: Might be related to the newest bug introduced by alsa-lib - See the answer to my question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479058/audacity-doesnt-work-with-pulseaudio-anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doping a bit of digging yielded [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-rc@lists.debian.org/msg514460.html). The latest version of `libasound2-plugins` fixes this:

`sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins=1.1.7-2`

Comment: yes, I read that bugs-file to, but don't know to how to read it. As to your answer, libasound2-plugins=1.1.7.-2 not found on repositories.

Comment: nvm @Cyclic3, I forgot to update my repo :). Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @PrasetyaPutra Happens to us all